# How to recover slice boundaries in Python?

Tags: python, slice

After defining a slice object like:

```
a = slice(0, 23)
```

how can one recover the boundary indices, i.e. 0 and 23 in this case?

Would I have to drop down to Cython, as suggested by the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/slice.html), and if so, what could be considered good practice for doing this as seamlessly as possible?

Comment: To all downvoters, about duplicate questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled

Comment: You only see C API accessors because you're looking at the C API docs. The Python-level docs are buried in the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#index-65) page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are stored in the attributes `start`, `stop` and `step`.

```
>>> a = slice(0, 23)
>>> a.start
0
>>> a.stop
23
>>> a.step is None
True
```

In general, questions like these are often quick and easy to solve by issueing `help(object_in_question)` in the interactive interpreter. `help(a)` will tell you

> Data descriptors defined here:
>
> start
>   step
>   stop

(In this instance, it is enough to know that descriptors are attributes on steroids.)

Comment: Woops, somehow I missed that... I thought that those were only arguments, not attributes. Thanks!